# Font-size in firefox is bigger than is should

Tags: css, fonts

I defined in my CSS file font-size property for the body

```
body {
  font-size : 12px;
}
```

I wanted to have the size of font the same as in http://www.stackexchange.com site.

It works in chromium browser but does not work in firefox. The size of font in firefox
is bigger.

Where could be the problem?

thank you

Comment: Can you give a link to your site? It's easier to answer your question then.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't actually *told* Firefox to do this, either via Zoom or a minimum font size?

Comment: @paulmorriss I have it only localy.

Comment: @Su' But stackexchange is OK in size. Is it possible that firefox applied zoom only to some pages and remembers this option for a long time? I sometimes change the keyboard and press zoom by mistake.

Comment: You can reset the zoom (on version 3) by choosing View->Zoom->Reset. On v3 and v4 you can press ctl and zero to reset it.

Comment: Thank you, zoom was the problem. Should I delete this question?

Comment: No, I think it's useful for other people to see that it might be their browser rather than the CSS that's the problem. I'll let @Su' put this in as an answer.

Comment: @Su' You can put this in as an answer if you want.

Comment: I had the same problem with css and FireFox.
The problem is fixed due to your tip. Thanks a lot!
The reason: I have installed the minimum font size = 24 in my FireFox (Tools-Options-Content-Advanced). Thus, I have actually told FireFox to do this.
The problem was solved after installing minimum font size = "none". Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out(see comments) to have been Firefox stashing a value for page zoom. Can be reset with Ctrl-0.